# Searching an open source RSS component, any suggestions?

Tags: rss

I am searching an open source RSS component to use in my project (.Net 3.5, C#). I have found ASP.Net RSS toolkit: http://aspnetrsstoolkit.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=3674. Do you know about advantages and disadvantages of the component? Could you suggest a better open source RSS component, if yes, what are pros and cons of the suggested component?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Could you specifiy what you want from the component? RSS feed only or display features? Web or fat client?

Answer (score 0):

There's also the [Argotic Syndication Framework](http://www.codeplex.com/Argotic).  I'd probably opt for that one over the one you named, but both should do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.
It seems like RSS Tool Kit works fine for me after that small fixes which I found on their forum.